# How to add an image attachment without uploading actual content?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Mirror SDK documentation says:
A list of media attachments associated with this item. As a convenience, you can refer to attachments in your HTML payloads with the attachment or cid scheme. For example:
attachment:  where attachment_index is the 0-based index of this array.
cid:  where attachment_id is the ID of the attachment.

Meaning that HTML payload can refer to attachments in the timeline item.
I want opposite way that html timeline item has an image, i would like to attach that image as an attachment using attachments[].contentUrl without uploading the stream, because there are case it throws exception saying "Stream does not support seek operation".
Simple question is :
Is it possible to set image url to attachments[0].contentUrl without uploading attachment stream?

Comment: Could you please share a bit more about your use case? I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't understand why you would want to do it.

Comment: video/vnd.google-glass.stream-url is supported, i was expecting same thing for URL. I want to show some of the recently (user)uploaded pictures to (user's) glass, these pictures are already available in Google Plus or photo share servers.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't a feature supported by the Mirror API. Attachments must be uploaded.

You can refer to images by URL using `img` html elements within the `html` property timeline item, though.

Comment: video/vnd.google-glass.stream-url is supported, i was expecting similar. I want to show some of the recently (user)uploaded pictures to (user's) glass, pic's are already available in Google Plus or photo share servers. I tried this, got exception "stream does not support seek oper.s" <pre><code>Stream stream = null;HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(imgUrl) as HttpWebRequest;HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;stream = response.GetResponseStream();service.Timeline.Insert(it, stream, "image/jpeg").Upload();
</code></pre>

Comment: I could copied to memory stream and pass the memory stream to upload, it should work, i'm thinking why it is not supported, is it because of copy right issue (i assume).

Comment: i have a url for the image , it works in html payload, why not it can be included as an attachment to share data for other share contract.

Comment: Ahh now I understad. You'd like to provide ongoing sharing. In this case, since it already exists on the web, the timelineItem.canonicalUrl property might be useful.